# Thread concurrency issue even within one single command?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am slightly surprised by what I get if I compile and run the following (horrible non-synchronized) Java SE program.

```
public class ThreadRace {

    // this is the main class.

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestRunnable tr=new TestRunnable(); // tr is a Runnable.
        Thread one=new Thread(tr,"thread_one");
        Thread two=new Thread(tr,"thread_two");

    one.start();
    two.start(); // starting two threads both with associated object tr.
    }
}

class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
    int counter=0; // Both threads can see this counter.

    public void run() {
    for(int x=0;x<1000;x++) {
        counter++;
    }
        // We can't get here until we've added one to counter 1000 times.
        // Can we??

    System.out.println("This is thread "+
      Thread.currentThread().getName()+" and the counter is "+counter);
    }
}
```

If I run "java ThreadRace" at the command line, then here is my interpretation
of what happens. Two new threads are created and started. The threads have
the same `Runnable` object instance `tr`, and so they see the same `tr.counter` .
Both new threads add one to this counter 1000 times, and then print the value
of the counter.

If I run this lots and lots of times, then usually I get output of the form

```
This is thread thread_one and the counter is 1000
This is thread thread_two and the counter is 2000
```

and occasionally I get output of the form

```
This is thread thread_one and the counter is 1204
This is thread thread_two and the counter is 2000
```

Note that what happened in this latter case was that thread_one finished
adding one to the counter 1000 times, but thread_two had started adding
one already, before thread_one printed out the value of the counter.
In particular, this output is still comprehensible to me.

However, very occasionally I get something like

```
This is thread thread_one and the counter is 1723
This is thread thread_two and the counter is 1723
```

As far as I can see, this "cannot happen". The only way the `System.out.println()` line
can be reached in either thread, is if the thread has finished counting to 1000.
So I am not bothered if *one* of the threads reports the counter as being some
random number between 1000 and 2000, but I cannot see how *both* threads can
get as far as their `System.out.println()` line (implying both for loops have finished,
surely?) and counter not be 2000 by the time the second statement is printed.

Is what is happening that both threads somehow attempt to do `counter++` at exactly
the same time, and one overwrites the other? That is, a thread can even be
interrupted even in the *middle* of executing a *single statement*?

Comment: You called it `ThreadRace`, so don't be surprised with race conditions.

Comment: You are facing the lost update phenomenon in the third case. Define `counter` to be `AtomicInteger`, if you dont want to use `synchronized`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "++" operator is not *atomic* -- it doesn't happen in one uninterruptible cycle. Think of it like this:

```
1. Fetch the old value
2. Add one to it
3. Store the new value back
```

So imagine that you get this sequence:

```
Thread A: Step 1
Thread B: Step 1
Thread A: Step 2
Thread B: Step 2
Thread A: Step 3
Thread B: Step 3
```

Both threads think they've incremented the variable, but its value has only increased by one! The second "store back" operation effectively cancels out the result of the first.

Now, truth is, when you add in multiple levels of cache, far weirder things can actually happen; but this is an easy explanation to understand. You can fix these kinds of issues by synchronizing access to the variable: either the whole `run()` method, or the inside of the loop using a synchronized block. As Jon suggests, you could also use some of the fancier tools in `java.util.concurrent.atomic`.

Comment: Kevin, if you want atomic operations use AtomicInteger and call incrementAndGet() on it. It is for this reason that this class exists.

Comment: Well, you learn something new every day. I had always assumed that a single-line command had to be atomic.

Comment: When you have a little time for experimenting, use the `javap -c` command to decompile your class files into readable JVM "assembly code", and you'll see how lines of Java translate into multiple JVM instructions. Of course, those are pretty high-level too, and often translate into multiple hardware instructions each!

Answer (score 4):

It *absolutely* can happen. `counter++` isn't an atomic operation. Consider it as:

```
int tmp = counter;
tmp++;
counter = tmp;
```

Now imagine two threads executing that code at the same about time:

- Both read the counter
- Both increment their local copy (0 to 1)
- Both write 1 into `counter`

This sort of thing is precisely why `java.util.concurrent.atomic` exists. Change your code to:

```
class TestRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public void run() {
      for(int x=0;x<1000;x++) {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
      }

      System.out.println("This is thread "+
        Thread.currentThread().getName()+" and the counter is " + counter.get());
   }
}
```

*That* code is safe.

Comment: Is there any way that I could somehow have figured out from looking at the docs that counter++ was not atomic? Or should I just assume that _nothing_ is atomic unless it's explicitly announced that it's atomic?

Comment: This comes from the Java memory model.  For all the formal goodness, see the Java Language Specification at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html, section 17.4.  The rough idea is that, unless your code says otherwise, the compiler is free to rearrange statements as long as the transformation won't modify the meaning of the code in a single-threaded environment.  And of course the CPU will rearrange instructions as a speed hack, unless you explicitly synchronize operations.

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: There's no need for the memory model to get involved here at all - no compiler rearranging. The problem is that there are three distinct operations here: read, increment, write.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard: Yes, you should assume that nothing is atomic unless it's explicitly stated. In particular, even though in this case each of the read and write aspects is individually atomic, that wouldn't necessarily be the case for `double` or `long` - see section 17.7 of the JLS.